# Merging multiple csv files without data shifting to the left

Tags: awk, csv, merge, paste

Im trying to merge several csv files into one big file. All these files have different column lengths and others only have a header (no data). When I use
`paste -d "," file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv file4.csv file5.csv file6.csv > output.csv` my final csv looks something like this [image]

Data from cgi_si2 should be on cgi_sii and data from cgi_sii should fall on a different column. file1.csv ranges from subjectkey to cgi_si, file2.csv is just cgi_si2 but just the header (`cat file2.csv cgi_si2`), files3.csv has cgi_sii with data numbers (its just one column), file4.csv has all those other headers but no data, file5.csv has a header and data (one column), and file6.csv are more headers with no data (`cat file6.csv cgi_efficacy_se,trt_grp,days_baseline,etc....`).

I have tried piping `| sed 's/^,//; s/,$//'> output.csv` but that has not worked.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a few lines of the files and the output you would expect from those example lines. We cannot help you parse data if we cannot see the data you want to parse. The image isn't informative since we don't know what the actual data are like.

Comment: Please, please, don't post Images of text data. Or at least provide the actual data in the question.

Comment: Also, please provide the source files since we don't know from which file comes each column.

Comment: I couldt find a way to upload the data, but heres a dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/abyyfh21k9ehhf7/AACnrBU5XfxBtQyRA3iBVDxRa?dl=0

Comment: @OmarMaximo The data in your files are all over the place. Some contain only headers (or a single header), other contains a single line of data (with a header), and the first file contains what looks like a real data set. It's unclear how you want to match these fragments up.  In particular `cgi_si2` is a lone header in the second file, and `cgi_sii` is a lone column with data in the third file.

Comment: @Kusalananda correct, not all data are perfect. Here's another approach: I have these headers and this file, how can I match the data from input_file.csv to match only the columns from cgi01_template.csv, but still keep the columns that have no data on a new csv file. These files can be found in the same dropbox link.

Comment: did you try it? do you need more information?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716713/195582

Answer (score 1):

This is an example. You have this kind of input files. they have different headers, and you have also a file without any content.

```
cat input_01.csv
subjectjey,cgi_si
a,2
b,3

cat input_02.csv
cgi_si2,cgi_sii
4,10
9,18

cat input_03.csv
cgi_si2

cat input_04.csv
cgi_sii
8
9
```

Using the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and running

```
mlr --csv rename -r '"cgi_si[0-9]+",cgi_si' then rename '"cgi_sii.+",cgi_sii' then unsparsify input_0*.csv
```

you will have

```
+------------+--------+---------+
| subjectjey | cgi_si | cgi_sii |
+------------+--------+---------+
| a          | 2      |         |
| b          | 3      |         |
|            | 4      | 10      |
|            | 9      | 18      |
|            |        | 8       |
|            |        | 9       |
+------------+--------+---------+
```

I use rename and regex to rename some fields and then I merge all.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do the task is manually. Open Excel/Calc, open each .csv one by one in the Excel (or text editor), and copy-paste from one file into another.

To do it automatically, you would have to go to a full-scale programming.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do! Wanna avoid all the manual work and just do it via a script